# The code is giving me an error that the name tweepy is not defined , and there occurs error in tweet.text that text attribute is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, nltk, tweepy

from textblob import TextBlob
import sys
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import nltk
import pycountry
import re
import string
#Sentiment Analysis
def percentage(part,whole):
return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)
keyword = input("Please enter keyword or hashtag to search: ")
noOfTweet = int(input ("Please enter how many tweets to analyze: "))
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_users, q=keyword).items(noOfTweet)
positive = 0
negative = 0
neutral = 0
polarity = 0
tweet_list = []
neutral_list = []
negative_list = []
positive_list = []
for tweet in tweets:

```
 #print(tweet.text)
 tweet_list.append(tweet.data)
 analysis = TextBlob(tweet.data)
 score = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer().polarity_scores(tweet.text)
 neg = score['neg']
 neu = score['neu']
 pos = score['pos']
 comp = score['compound']
 polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity
 negative += 1
 if(pos > neg):
   positive_list.append(tweet.text)
   positive += 1
 
 elif pos == neg:
  neutral_list.append(tweet.text)
  neutral += 1
positive = percentage(positive, noOfTweet)
negative = percentage(negative, noOfTweet)
neutral = percentage(neutral, noOfTweet)
polarity = percentage(polarity, noOfTweet)
positive = format(positive, '.1f')
negative = format(negative, '.1f')
neutral = format(neutral, '.1f')
```

Comment: Have you installed Tweepy?

Comment: yes , I have installed tweepy.

Comment: also there is an error in : tweet_list.append(tweet.text)
 analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text) ,  that text attribute is not defined...So , can you guide me? @Mickael Martinez

Comment: Please add format to your code: currently it's hard to follow it. Sorry but I can't edit it at the moment (edit queue is full). Need to write your code starting with  `\`\`\`python` then just copy and paste your code, and close the block again with `\`\`\``. In addition to this, include your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `api.search_users()` method, which returns `User` objects and not `Tweet` objects (see the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets)), so they don't have any `text` attribute.

You should use the `api.search_tweets()` method instead (see the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets)).